# Is negligible resistance a problem?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

Negligible resistance in a conductor is said to be a problem in many cases such as in the case of [carbon nanotubes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube). One thing that I do not understand is that sometimes people say that low resistance is good but no resistance is not. In other situations it contradicts a lot of theories. For instance if we consider a wire with negligible resistance, it cannot mean that the current would  be very high because then it will contradict the ohm's law. Lets say in the case of CNTs why is low resistance a problem? in a way low resistance means high conductivity which should be good and in another there's the problem of impedance matching and ohm's law. Why is resistance so important? or is it so important as we have been believing as per the theories given by the scientists? Can someone answer this?

Comment: Please can you provide a reference which says that low resistance is a problem in carbon nanotubes? ... Low resistance could be a problem or an advantage depending on what the purpose is. Unless you identify the purpose, the question cannot be answered.

Comment: Without specifying an application it's not at all clear what you mean by "good". For example, if I want to build a resistor, a material with zero resistance is not good. If I want to transmit power, then a material with low resistance is good. Please be *specific*.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it would be very desirable to have zero resistance, it does not contradict laws, it only means there is no dissipation through conductors.

Which would be really good!.

That is actually a research benefit of superconductors.